# Preimage of a variety under a morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is the preimage of a variety a variety, or is the preimage of an affine variety an affine variety?

More precisely, Let $X,Y$ prevarieties, $\varphi: X \to Y$ a morphism. given a (affine) variety $Z \subset Y$, is $\varphi^{-1}(Z)$ a (affine) variety?

My definition is the following, an affine variety is a topological space $X$ with a sheaf of $k$ algebras that is isomorphic a to an algebraic set, a prevariety is just something locally isomorphic to an affine variety and a variety is a prevariety satisfying the "Hausdorff" propriety.

EDIT: what can you say if $X$ is a variety?

Comment: Sorry, originally I didn't pay attention to the "non-Hausdorff" part. So the answer to both questions is no: let $Y$ be a point, and $X$ a non-separated (that is, "non-Hausdorff") prevariety.

Comment: Thanks @AsalBeagDubh, i added and edit to the post... it's hard to me to assimilate something that isn't preserved by pre images

Comment: As I mentioned originally, even if $X$ is a variety the affine version is still negative: let $Y$ be a point and $X$ a non-affine variety.